# Download Zip file corrupted in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip

I'm using this function to create and download ZIP files. It works well for less than 200MB files, I tested. When I tried to download More than 250MB files then download stops partially and while opening it shows corrupted.

```
    public function download_songs($bs_id){
    // public function download_songs(){
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->load->helper('file');
    $this->load->helper('download');
    // $bs_id       = $this->input->post('bs_id');

    $bsl_data       = $this->public_model->get_result_array_with_one_where('buy_song_list','psl_bs_id',$bs_id);
    $bal_data       = $this->public_model->get_result_array_with_one_where('buy_album_list','bal_bs_id',$bs_id);

    $d_type = 0;
    foreach($bsl_data as $bs_row){
        $dateA = $bs_row['psl_created']; 
        // your second date coming from a mysql database (date fields) 
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $dateB = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

        $timediff = strtotime($dateB) - strtotime($dateA);

        //if($timediff>10800){ // echo 'more than 3 hours';
        if($timediff > 86400){  //echo 'more than 24 hours';
            $this->db->where('psl_mml_id',$bs_row['psl_mml_id'])
                    ->set('psl_status','1')
                    ->update('buy_song_list');
            $d_type = 0;
        }
        else{
            // echo 'less than 3 hours';            
            if($bs_row['psl_status']=='0'){                 
                $mml_data = $this->public_model->get_result_array('music_mp3_list','','','mml_id',$bs_row['psl_mml_id']);                   
                if($bs_row['psl_file_type']=='MP3'){
                    $f = $mml_data['mml_mp3'];
                }
                if($bs_row['psl_file_type']=='MP4'){
                     $f = $mml_data['mml_mp4'];
                }                   
                $ex_p = explode('?',$f);
                $path = "public_html/upload/music_mp3/".$ex_p[0];
                $this->zip->read_file($path);
                $d_type = 1;    
            }else{
                $d_type = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($bal_data as $ba_row){
        $dateA = $ba_row['bal_created']; 
        // your second date coming from a mysql database (date fields) 
        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $dateB = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 

        $timediff = strtotime($dateB) - strtotime($dateA);

        // if($timediff > 10800){ //echo 'more than 3 hours';
        if($timediff > 86400){  //echo 'more than 24 hours';

            $this->db->where('bal_mal_id',$ba_row['bal_mal_id'])
                        ->set('bal_status','1')
                        ->update('buy_album_list');
            $d_type = 0;
        }
        else{
            if($ba_row['bal_status']=='0'){             
                $mal_mml_data = $this->public_model->get_result_array_with_one_where('music_mp3_list','mml_mal_id',$ba_row['bal_mal_id']);
                foreach($mal_mml_data as $re_row){
                    if($ba_row['bal_file_type']=='MP3'){
                        $f = $re_row['mml_mp3'];
                    }
                    if($ba_row['bal_file_type']=='MP4'){
                        $f = $re_row['mml_mp4'];
                    }

                    if($ba_row['bal_file_type']=='full_album'){
                        $f = $re_row['mml_mp3'];
                    }

                    $ex_p = explode('?',$f);
                    $path = "public_html/upload/music_mp3/".$ex_p[0];
                    $this->zip->read_file($path);
                    $d_type = 1;
                }   
            }else{
                $d_type = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if($d_type=='1'){
        ob_end_clean();
        $zip_f_name = 'gravity_'.date('Y_m_d_His').'.zip';
        $this->zip->download($zip_f_name);
    }else{
        $data['waring_msg'] = 'Sorry this file already downloaded.';
        $this->load->view('paypal_status',$data);

    }

}
```

Also used  function **ob_end_clean();** from earlier questions but still issue persists

Comment: Maybe your php process run out of memory ?

Comment: @Gwendal Its not. I checked

Comment: Rewrite your code to use php's native `ZipArchive` and see if the problem persists. I believe there is a limit as to how many files you can add at at time and you have to close and open the archive before reaching that limit to continue adding files. Its really hard to say what the issue may be.

Comment: The issue is because of am not saving the generating zip files anywhere.if they saved and tried to download it works well.

Comment: Its limited by server, since iam using shared server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hosting provider limiting the size of files that can be generated.